# Very strange beahviour concerning c# null propagation + null coalescing operator

Tags: c#

Consider this code:

```
//get a list that might be null, empty or valid
 var myItems = _myRepo.GetForId(someId);

 if (!myItems?.Any() ?? true)
 {
     throw new Exception();
 }
 //valid list
```

this code might be a little confusing at the beginning but nicely handles (=short) an empty list or a null reference.

I even wrote a short unit test just to make sure I am not fooling myself here. It passes:

```
[TestMethod]
public void SomeOtherTest()
{
    //interace that is implemented by _myRepo from code above
    var myRepo = Mock.Create<IMyRepo>();
    myRepo.Arrange(ar => ar.GetForId(Arg.AnyGuid)).Returns(() => null);

    var myItems = myRepo.GetForId(Guid.Empty);

    if (!myItems?.Any() ?? true)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        Assert.Fail();
    }

    myRepo = Mock.Create<ImyRepo>();

    myRepo.Arrange(ar => ar.GetForId(Arg.AnyGuid)).Returns(() => new List<MyItem>());

    myItems = myRepo.GetForId(Guid.Empty);

    if (!myItems?.Any() ?? true)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        Assert.Fail();
    }

    myRepo = Mock.Create<ImyRepo>();

    myRepo.Arrange(ar => ar.GetForId(Arg.AnyGuid)).Returns(() => new List<MyItem> {new MyItem()});

    myItems = myRepo.GetForId(Guid.Empty);

    if (!myItems?.Any() ?? true)
    {
        Assert.Fail();
    }
    else
    {      
    }
}
```

But then something really weird is happening:

In another (my actual) unit test I setup like this:

```
 myRepo.Arrange(ar => ar.GetForId(Arg.AnyGuid)).Returns(() => new List<MyItem> {new MyItem()});
```

which is excactly like I did in the passing unit test and the very same code behaves different:

```
 myItems = myRepo.GetForId(Guid.Empty);

 if (!myItems?.Any() ?? true)
 {
    //debugger stops here
 }
 else
 { 
 }
```

mouseover reveals `myItems.Count==1`
which should result in talking the else branch.
I really do not have any idea how this is possible..

update:

[image]

Comment: It's likely not to do with your `if` condition then. Maybe it has to do with your `GetForId` implementation?

Comment: It would be easier to follow this if you'd show a [mcve] showing the surprising behaviour - just a console app we can copy/paste/compile/run.

Comment: For debugging purposes, do the following: Change your if-statement from `if (!myItems?.Any() ?? true)` to `if (myItems == null | myItems.Count == 0)`, and run your test again. If this evaluates to true, then we know that the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @JohnLBevan Linq's `.Any()` extension with an empty predicate returns true if the list contains anything at all, including `null`. The `??` operator only ever evaluates if the list itself is null.

Comment: If `myItems` really has `Count == 1` then it will hit the `else` condition. Even if the item it contains is `null`. There must be something else going on. See JonSkeet 's request please.

Comment: I can't replicate this.  When I do, it falls into the else block.

Comment: If you consider the passing unit tests which test the very same scenario and with the very same arrangement, I would assume that this behaviour is caused by something else. Could it be related to the fact, that I use dependency injection to get the repository instance in my actual unit test?

Comment: I just got the suspicion that this only happens in debug mode. I'll check this and let you know

Comment: Yep. When I am not in debug mode the code executes as expected.